# Java - Rotating array

Tags: java, arrays, rotation

So the goal is to rotate the elements in an array right `a` times.
As an example; if `a==2`, then     `array = {0,1,2,3,4}` would become `array = {3,4,0,1,2}`

Here's what I have:

```
for (int x = 0; x <= array.length-1; x++){
    array[x+a] = array[x];
}
```

However, this fails to account for when `[x+a]` is greater than the length of the array. I read that I should store the ones that are greater in a different Array but seeing as `a` is variable I'm not sure that's the best solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Modulo is your friend.

Comment: `x < array.length` is cleaner and more conventional than `x <= array.length-1`.

Comment: The way you are doing it will overwrite some values of the array. You really should write into a new array.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Add a modulo array length to your code:

```
// create a newArray before of the same size as array

// copy
for(int x = 0; x <= array.length-1; x++){
  newArray[(x+a) % array.length ] = array[x];
}
```

You should also create a new `Array` to copy to, so you do not overwrite values, that you'll need later on.

Comment: Is there a better way without having to use the extra temp memory (variable newArray) ?

Comment: @void I guess you will at least need one variable to store some temporary values. It should be possible, but the code would get much more complicated.

Comment: Also, the algorithm won't be O(n), but O(n*k), because you need to swap out into the temporary variable all the time, it's called bubble rotate or something, similar to bubble sort. O(1) space, O(n*k) time.

Comment: What if we plug in a negative value for a, though? Wouldn't the modulo operator create negative numbers as an index?
i.e. (0 + -1) % 3 would be -1, and indexing at -1 would cause an IndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: @AgentM You're right. In such cases you should use the fact that the result of a rotation by `a` is the same as as using `array.length + a`. Using that fact, you can transform your `a` to a positive int before the for loop.

Comment: The OP question was to rotate the array, not create a rotated copy.

Answer (score 30):

In case you don't want to reinvent the wheel (maybe it's an exercise but it can be good to know), you can use `Collections.rotate`.

Be aware that it requires an array of objects, not primitive data type (otherwise you'll swap arrays themselves in the list).

```
Integer[] arr = {0,1,2,3,4};
Collections.rotate(Arrays.asList(arr), 2);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr)); //[3, 4, 0, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 11):

Arraycopy is an expensive operation, both time and memory wise.
Following would be an efficient way to rotate array without using extra space (unlike the accepted answer where a new array is created of the same size).

```
public void rotate(int[] nums, int k) { // k = 2
    k %= nums.length;
    // {0,1,2,3,4}

    reverse(nums, 0, nums.length - 1); // Reverse the whole Array
    // {4,3,2,1,0}

    reverse(nums, 0, k - 1); // Reverse first part (4,3 -> 3,4)
    // {3,4,2,1,0}

    reverse(nums, k, nums.length - 1); //Reverse second part (2,1,0 -> 0,1,2)
    // {3,4,0,1,2}
}

public void reverse(int[] nums, int start, int end) {
    while (start < end) {
        int temp = nums[start];
        nums[start] = nums[end];
        nums[end] = temp;
        start++;
        end--;
    }
}
```

Comment: Complexity of this method will be O(2n). NOt impressive

Comment: Clever approach, however I am afraid that this algorithm would be inefficient for large Array's as the time complexity is 3 * O(n). 

System.arraycopy() on the other hand is a native method which will copy elements at memory level, it should be faster for cases where your Array is large.

Comment: The goal of this answer was to provide a solution that doesn't use extra space, I should have been clear in the answer itself. (Editing it).

@Ekansh Well, I could be wrong but it seems to me the reversal of an array would have the effective time complexity of O(N), which the best you can get to rotate the array as there can not be a solution with O(1).

Arif as per my knowledge 3*O(N) is still O(N). And System.arraycopy() also has the same time complexity of O(N).

Comment: @ThePatelGuy you have great answer, but I made simple update and now algorithm works as I need  1) reverse(nums, 0, nums.length - 1);
2) reverse(nums, 0, nums.length - k - 1);
3) reverse(nums, nums.length - k, nums.length - 1);

Comment: Comments about O(N) times a constant reveal low understanding of the asymptotic notation. In addition, the factor 3 is plain wrong (only 2 moves are performed per element).

Answer (score 2):

I think the fastest way would be using [System.arrayCopy()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)) which is native method:

```
int[] tmp = new int[a];
System.arraycopy(array, array.length - a, tmp, 0, a);
System.arraycopy(array, 0, array, a, array.length - a);
System.arraycopy(tmp, 0, array, 0, a);
```

It also reuses existing array. It may be beneficial in some cases. 
And the last benefit is the temporary array size is less than original array. So you can reduce memory usage when `a` is small.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is copying with [System.arraycopy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29).

```
    int[] temp = new int[array.length];
    System.arraycopy(array, 0, temp, a, array.length - a);
    System.arraycopy(array, array.length-a, temp, 0, a);
```

Answer (score 1):

Time Complexity = O(n)

Space Complexity = O(1)

The algorithm starts with the first element of the array (newValue) and places it at its position after the rotation (newIndex). The element that was at the newIndex becomes oldValue. After that, oldValue and newValue are swapped.

This procedure repeats length times.

The algorithm basically bounces around the array placing each element at its new position.

```
unsigned int computeIndex(unsigned int len, unsigned int oldIndex, unsigned int times) {
    unsigned int rot = times % len;
    unsigned int forward = len - rot;

    // return (oldIndex + rot) % len; // rotating to the right
    return (oldIndex + forward) % len; // rotating to the left
}

void fastArrayRotation(unsigned short *arr, unsigned int len, unsigned int rotation) {
    unsigned int times = rotation % len, oldIndex, newIndex, length = len;
    unsigned int setIndex = 0;
    unsigned short newValue, oldValue, tmp;

    if (times == 0) {
        return;
    }

    while (length > 0) {
        oldIndex = setIndex;
        newValue = arr[oldIndex];
        while (1) {
            newIndex = computeIndex(len, oldIndex, times);
            oldValue = arr[newIndex];
            arr[newIndex] = newValue;

            length--;

            if (newIndex == setIndex) { // if the set has ended (loop detected)
                break;
            }

            tmp = newValue;
            newValue = oldValue;
            oldValue = tmp;

            oldIndex = newIndex;
        }
        setIndex++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] rotate(int[] array, int r) {
    final int[] out = new int[array.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        out[i] = (i < r - 1) ? array[(i + r) % array.length] : array[(i + r) % array.length];
    }
    return out;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following rotate method will behave exactly the same as the rotate method from the Collections class used in combination with the subList method from the List interface, i.e. rotate  (n, fromIndex, toIndex, dist)  where n is an array of ints will give the same result as Collections.rotate (Arrays.asList (n).subList (fromIndex, toIndex), dist) where n is an array of Integers.

First create a swap method:

```
public static void swap (int[] n, int i, int j){

   int tmp = n[i];
   n[i] = n[j];
   n[j] = tmp;
}
```

Then create the rotate method:

```
public static void rotate (int[] n, int fromIndex, int toIndex, 
int dist){

   if(fromIndex > toIndex)

      throw new IllegalArgumentException ("fromIndex (" + 
         fromIndex + ") > toIndex (" + toIndex + ")");

   if (fromIndex < toIndex){

      int region = toIndex - fromIndex;
      int index;

      for (int i = 0; i < dist % region + ((dist < 0) ? region : 0); 
              i++){

         index = toIndex - 1;
     
         while (index > fromIndex)

            swap (n, index, --index);
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Question : https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ctci-array-left-rotation
Solution :
This is how I tried arrayLeftRotation method with complexity o(n)

- looping once from k index to (length-1 )
- 2nd time for 0 to kth index

  public static int[] arrayLeftRotation(int[] a, int n, int k) {
      int[] resultArray = new int[n];
      int arrayIndex = 0;
      //first n-k indexes will be populated in this loop
      for(int i = k ; i 
          resultArray[arrayIndex] = a[i];
          arrayIndex++;
      }
      // 2nd k indexes will be populated in this loop
      for(int j=arrayIndex ; j<(arrayIndex+k); j++){
          resultArray[j]=a[j-(n-k)];
      }
      return resultArray;
  }

Answer (score 0):

Java solution wrapped in a method:

```
public static int[] rotate(final int[] array, final int rIndex) {
    if (array == null || array.length <= 1) {
        return new int[0];
    }

    final int[] result = new int[array.length];
    final int arrayLength = array.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        int nIndex = (i + rIndex) % arrayLength;
        result[nIndex] = array[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Left Rotate its very simple

Take the difference between length of the array and number of position to shift.

For Example

```
int k = 2;
int n = 5;

int diff = n - k;

int[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int[] result = new int[array.length];
System.arraycopy(array, 0, result, diff, k);
System.arraycopy(array, k, result, 0, diff);
```

// print the output

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.array.orderstatistics;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayRotation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = scan.nextInt();
        int r = scan.nextInt();
        int[] a = new int[n];
        int[] b = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            a[i] = scan.nextInt();
        }
        scan.close();

        if (r % n == 0) {
            printOriginalArray(a);
        } else {
            r = r % n;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                b[i] = a[(i + r) < n ? (i + r) : ((i + r) - n)];
                System.out.print(b[i] + " ");
            }
        }
    }

    private static void printOriginalArray(int[] a) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following routine rotates an array in java:

```
public static int[] rotateArray(int[] array, int k){
    int to_move = k % array.length;
    if(to_move == 0)
      return array;
    for(int i=0; i< to_move; i++){
      int temp = array[array.length-1];
      int j=array.length-1;
      while(j > 0){
        array[j] = array[--j];
      }
      array[0] = temp;
    }
    return array;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below

```
class Solution {
    public void rotate(int[] nums, int k) {
        if (k==0) return;
        if (nums == null || nums.length == 0) return;

        for(int i=0;i<k;i++){
            int j=nums.length-1;
            int temp = nums[j];
            for(;j>0;j--){
                nums[j] = nums[j-1];
            }
            nums[0] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

In the above solution, `k` is the number of times you want your array to rotate from left to right.

Answer (score -1):

Question : Rotate array given a specific distance .
Method 1 : 
Turn the int array to ArrayList. Then use Collections.rotate(list,distance).

```
class test1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

        List<Integer> list = Arrays.stream(a).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());

        Collections.rotate(list, 3);
        System.out.println(list);//[4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3]

    }// main
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I use this, just loop it `a` times

```
public void rotate(int[] arr) {
    int temp = arr[arr.length - 1];

    for(int i = arr.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        arr[i] = arr[i - 1];
    }

    arr[0] = temp;
}
```