# Shifter program

Tags: java, arrays

So I have a Shifter program that only allows positive integers. 
*Question*: how do I make it so It also receives negative numbers. I.e 
 
Program ask for number of shifts, I enter 3 and it outputs 
`3 2 1 15 14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4`

```
 public static void shiftRight(int[] list)
 {
     if (list.length < 2) return;

     int last = list[list.length - 1];

     for(int i = list.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
         list[i] = list[i - 1];
     }
     list[0] = last;
 }
```

if this is to shift right. How would I make it so It will shift depending on the number I input? i.e. Right for positive and Left for negative.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Your code does not take an int as a parameter, it takes an array and only shifts it one position.  I can only assume you have another function that calls `shiftRight` multiple times that you're not showing us for some reason.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko I just updated and my question is there

Comment: Are you allowed to create new array? In that case take a look at [Java - Rotating array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26610309/java-rotating-array)

Answer (score 0):

I would implement a `shiftLeft(int[])` method according your method, and then decide which use

```
int input;
int[] array;
//fill the input, array etc. 
if(input<0){
    for(int i=0;i<-input;i++){
        shiftLeft(array);
    }
}else{
    for(int i=0;i<input;i++){
        shiftRight(array);
    }
}
```

btw, this shifting is not very efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following function. It uses a temporary array to store the rotated/shifted array and then copies back to the original array. The arrays that is original array and temporary array are traversed twice, so it will be efficient instead for calling a shift function on the array many times.

```
/**
 * This function performs the right/left shift operations
 * on the array of integers.
 *
 * @param   int[]   array   array of integers
 * @param   int     shift   Amount of right or
 *                          left shift. If shift
 *                          is grater than zero, 
 *                          function performs
 *                          right shift, otherwise
 *                          the function perform
 *                          left shift.
 */
public static void shift_array (int[] array, int shift) {

    /*
     * If array is null, then return 
     * from the function.
     */
    if (array == null) {
        return;
    }

    boolean is_left_shift = (shift < 0); // store whether   
                                         // left shift is
                                         // intended.
    int shift_amount;   // store the amount of shift
    int array_length = array.length;    // length of the 
                                        // array

    if (shift < 0) {
        shift_amount = shift * -1; // if shift is less than zero
                                   // then shift_amount is set as 
                                   // product of shift and -1.
    } else {
        shift_amount = shift;
    }

    /*
     * Make sure the shift_amount is within the
     * length of the array.
     */     
    shift_amount = shift_amount % array_length;

    /*
     * If the shift_amount is zero, we 
     * have nothing to do. Return.
     */
    if (shift_amount == 0) {
        return;
    }

    /*
     * Create a temp array and copy the 
     * elements in the array at appropriate
     * positions.
     */
    if (!is_left_shift) {

        /*
         * Temp array to store elements at shifted
         * positions.
         */
        int[] temp = new int[array_length];

        /*
         * Iterate throught the array
         */ 
        for (int i = 0; i < array_length; ++i) {

            int temp_index;

            /*
             * Map the elements to appropriate 
             * positions in the temp array.
             */
            if ((i + shift_amount) < array_length) {
                temp_index = i + shift_amount;      
            } else {
                temp_index = (i + shift_amount) % array_length;;        
            }

            /*
             * Copy the array element into the temp array.
             */ 
            temp[temp_index] = array[i]; 
        }

        /*
         * Copy back from temp array to array
         */
        for (int i = 0; i < array_length; ++i) {
            array[i] = temp[i];
        }
    } else {

        /*
         * Temp array to store elements at shifted
         * positions.
         */
        int[] temp = new int[array_length];

        /*
         * Iterate throught the array
         */ 
        for (int i = 0; i < array_length; ++i) {

            int temp_index;

            /*
             * Map the elements to appropriate 
             * positions in the temp array.
             */
            if ((i - shift_amount) >= 0) {
                temp_index = i - shift_amount;
            } else {
                temp_index = i - shift_amount + array_length;
            }

            /*
             * Copy the array element into the temp array.
             */ 
            temp[temp_index] = array[i]; 
        }

        /*
         * Copy back from temp array to array
         */
        for (int i = 0; i < array_length; ++i) {
            array[i] = temp[i];
        }
    }
}
```