# Adding indexes of a list to a new list

Tags: java, list, indexing, addition

Given an array of ints length 3, return an array with the elements "rotated left" so {1, 2, 3} yields {2, 3, 1}.

My first attempt(I had done this in python easily so I had the same idea).

```
public int[] rotateLeft3(int[] nums) {
      return [nums[1:] + nums[0]];
}
```

But as you expected I got an error, so I immediately wrote this.

```
public int[] rotateLeft3(int[] nums) {
    int[] answer = new int[3];
    answer[0] = nums[1];
    answer[1] = nums[2];
    answer[2] = nums[0];
    return answer;
}
```

I feel like this is possibly the most inefficient way to answer the question, but I only did this because it says of length 3. My previous code works in python for all sizes. So I was wondering how would my previous code be written in java?

Comment: Write a loop that steps through the elements and moves them. Show us the loop that you write and we will help you with it.

Answer (score 0):

with collection:
[Java - Rotating array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26610309/java-rotating-array)

use Integer nums[];

if not, iterate and convert your int[] to Integer[]

or use http://commons.apache.org/lang/ :

```
Integer[] array2= ArrayUtils.toObject(nums);

Collections.rotate(Arrays.asList(nums), -1);
```

convert to array : .toArray();

Answer (score 0):

Maybe...

```
public int[] rotateLeft(int size, int[] array) {
  int temp = int[size-1]; // We're just gonna save the las value.
  for (int i = size-1; i == 0; i--) {
    array[i] = array[i-1]; // We move them all 1 to the left.
  }
  array[0] = temp; // This is why we saved the las value.

  return array;
```

Hope it helped you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that easily with [System.arraycopy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-):

```
int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3};
int[] rotated = new int[arr.length];
System.arraycopy(arr, 1, rotated, 0, arr.length - 1);
rotated[arr.length-1] = arr[0];
```