# How can i shift Values in Arrays that are in an Array?

Tags: java, arrays

I have this assignment in my coding class where i need to shift values a certain amount over inside of arrays that are in an array. It's really confusing for me.
I can't use `java.util` and I can't use Arraylists.
(it's not allowed by the assignment and I don't know what those are anyways)

First I get the array:

```
[
[ ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ]
[X, X, X, X, X,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ]
[X,  ,  ,  , X,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ]
[X, X, X, X, X,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ]
]
```

and after shifting the values by e.g. 2 I want it to look like this:

```
[
[ ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ]
[ ,  , X, X, X, X, X,  ,  ,  ,  ]
[ ,  , X,  ,  ,  , X,  ,  ,  ,  ]
[ ,  , X, X, X, X, X,  ,  ,  ,  ]
]
```

and after shifting "over the edge of the array" e.g. 8 I want it to look like this:

```
[
[ ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ]
[X, X,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  , X, X, X]
[ , X,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  , X,  ,  ]
[X, X,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  , X, X, X]
]
```

My solutions so far have looked like this:
This one I tried creating myself:

```
System.out.println("src:");
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(ArrayOfArrays));

for (int i = 0; i < ArrayOfArraysShifted.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < fieldWidth; j++) }
        *logic (read text below)
        ArrayOfArraysShifted[i][j + shift] = ArrayOfArrays[i][j];
    }
}

System.out.println("dest:");
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(ArrayOfArraysShifted));
```

For some reason it just doesn't print the ArrayOfArraysShifted at the end.
And I had some logic where the logic is for when the shift goes "over the edge" but I didn't save it after it failed.

This one i got from another StackOverflow post about shifting in an Array:

```
int shift = askNumber("Shift by how much?");

if (shift > ArrayOfArrays.length) {
shift = shift % ArrayOfArrays.length;
}

System.arraycopy(ArrayOfArrays, ArrayOfArrays.length - shift, ArrayOfArrayShifted, 0, shift);

for (int k = 0; k < ArrayOfArraysFromLinesShifted.length; k++) {
    for (int l = 0; l < fieldWidth; l++) {
        ArrayOfArraysFromLinesShifted[k] [l + shift] = ArrayOfArraysFromLines[k] [l];
    }
}

System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(ArrayOfArraysFromLinesShifted));
```

Comment: Your first step should be to get the shifting in a simple array to work. Ie `[1,2,3,4] -- > [3,4,1,2]`. If you have mastered that one, just apply it on all rows of the 2D array ...

Comment: @derpirscher is there a way to seperate the arrays inside? if yes how?

Comment: That depends on you you defined the whole data structure. If you have something like `int[][] foo = new int[5][10]` then yes ... Because then `foo` is just an array of arrays, and each `foo[i]` is a simple array itself which doesn't have anything to do with any of the other arrays

Comment: String[][] ArrayOfArrays = new String[IntegerValueFromAnotherMethod][DifferentIntegerValueFromAnotherMethod]; If this works with your idea could you please point me in the direction of an explanation for pulling those arrays apart?

Comment: @Benneck hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are describing is more of a rotate than a shift. Here is one way.  It is very simple and allows for left and right rotations.  A `negative` count rotates counter clockwise or to the `left`, a `positive` count clock wise or towards the `right`.

- First, ensure the array can be or needs to be rotated.  The rotation of an array of one element doesn't alter the array.  Nor does a rotation of `0` or the `length` of the array or any multiple of the length of the array.
- A negative rotation count is adjusted to an equivalent positive one.

  - count is always adjusted to `count%len`
  - then count is negated to conform to rotational directions.
  - if count is negative, it is adjusted to `len + count`

Once the values are adjusted, a temp array of length count is created.

- the first `count` values are copied into this array.
- the the original array is shifted left `count` values.
- then the temp array added into the array in proper order.

```
 public static void rotate(Object[] array, int count) {
     int len = array.length;
     if (len < 2 || count%len == 0) {
         return; // no rotation needed
     }
     count %= len;

     count = -count; // done to satisfy left and right direction
     if(count < 0) {
         count = len + count;
     }

     Object[] temp = new Object[count];
     
     for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
         temp[i] = array[i];
     }

     for (int i = count; i < len; i++) {
         array[i - count] = array[i];
     }

     for (int k = 0, i = len - count; i < len; i++) {
         array[i] = temp[k++];
     }
 }
```

To print you can do this.   Presumes `arrays` is `new someType[][] arrays ...`

```
for (Object[] obj : arrays) {
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(obj));
}
```

One final note.  Using an Object array (e.g. `Object[]`) will not allow you to rotate primitive arrays(e.g. `int, long, double`, etc).  You will need a separate rotate method for each primitive type.

Comment: Oh my god this is it. Thank you so much!

Comment: Your most welcome.

Comment: Maybe a dumb question but what goes in the brackets behind "rotate()" if i use it in another method? nvm i found it

Comment: @Benneck All you do is call it with a single array.  e.g.  `rotate(myArray);`  Since the array is modified in place, no return value is required.  I used `Object[]` in the method so any array could be rotated.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: Yes. again thank you very much i changed it a bit with my naming scheme and i works like a charm.

Comment: What is the time complexity of this rotation?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to produce logic for rotating one array before you can address all of them. Once you have that logic, you can use a simple loop on the 2D array to rotate all the 1D arrays.

I think the easiest approach would be [Collections.rotate(List<?>, int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#rotate-java.util.List-int-), but since you cannot use `java.util`, I would try [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26610358/5645656). Here's my own implementation, which introduces a `delta` variable to prevent an [`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html). The time complexity is `O(N)`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[][] arrays = {
                { " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " " },
                { "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " " },
                { "X", " ", " ", " ", "X", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " " },
                { "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " " }
            };

    System.out.println("Original:\n" + prettyPrintArray(arrays));
    for (int i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++)
        arrays[i] = rotateArray(arrays[i], 8);
    System.out.println("Rotated:\n" + prettyPrintArray(arrays));
}

private static <E> E[] rotateArray(E[] array, int amount) {
    int arrayLength = array.length;
    if (arrayLength < 2 || amount == 0)
        return array;

    int delta = amount % arrayLength;
    E[] temporary = (E[]) Array.newInstance(array[0].getClass(), arrayLength);
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++)
        temporary[(i + delta) % arrayLength] = array[i];

    return temporary;
}

private static String prettyPrintArray(Object[][] array) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("[");

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (i != 0)
            builder.append(',');

        builder.append("\n\t[");
        Object[] elements = array[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < elements.length; j++) {
            if (j != 0)
                builder.append(',');
            builder.append(elements[j]);
        }

        builder.append("]");
    }

    return builder.append("\n]").toString();
}
```

This is the output:

```
Original:
[
    [ , , , , , , , , , , ],
    [X,X,X,X,X, , , , , , ],
    [X, , , ,X, , , , , , ],
    [X,X,X,X,X, , , , , , ]
]
Rotated:
[
    [ , , , , , , , , , , ],
    [X,X, , , , , , ,X,X,X],
    [ ,X, , , , , , ,X, , ],
    [X,X, , , , , , ,X,X,X]
]
```

Comment: The question explicitly says "*I can't use `java.util`*"

Comment: @Cardinal System Unfortunately Java.util things are not allowed but thanks for your trying :)

Comment: thank you very much for taking the time.

Comment: @Cardinal System I'm still in the process of trying to understand the code so i wont close thequestion yet if thats alright.

Comment: @derpirscher you're right. I updated my answer.